# WebClient instrumentation in spring sleuth

Tags: spring-cloud-sleuth

I'm wondering whether sleuth has reactive WebClient instrumentation supported.

I did't find it from the document:

*Instruments common ingress and egress points from Spring applications (servlet filter, async endpoints, rest template, scheduled actions, message channels, Zuul filters, and Feign client).*

My case:

I may use WebClient in either a WebFilter or my rest resource to produce Mono.

And I want:

- A sub span auto created as child of root span
- trace info propagated via headers

If the instrumentation is not supported at the moment, Am I supposed to manually get the span from context and do it by myself like this:

[OpenTracing instrumentation on reactive WebClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50600040/opentracing-instrumentation-on-reactive-webclient)

Thanks

Leon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to Sleuth's documentation for the Finchley release train, and you do `find` and you search for `WebClient` you'll find it - https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Finchley.RC2/single/spring-cloud.html#__literal_webclient_literal .  In other words we do support it out of the box.

UPDATE:

New link - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current/reference/html/integrations.html#sleuth-http-client-webclient-integration

let me paste the contents

> 3.2.2. WebClient
>
> This feature is available for all tracer implementations.
>
> We inject a ExchangeFilterFunction implementation that creates a span
> and, through on-success and on-error callbacks, takes care of closing
> client-side spans.
>
> To block this feature, set spring.sleuth.web.client.enabled to false.
> You have to register WebClient as a bean so that the tracing
> instrumentation gets applied. If you create a WebClient instance with
> a new keyword, the instrumentation does NOT work.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just found  TraceWebClientBeanPostProcessor which helps.

Comment: Can you put a code example? Link is broken

Answer (score 7):

Even though this is an old question this would help others...

WebClient instrumentation will only work if new instance is created via Spring as a Bean. Check [Spring Cloud Sleuth reference guide](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-sleuth/2.2.0.M1/#_webclient).

> You have to register WebClient as a bean so that the tracing instrumentation gets applied. If you create a WebClient instance with a new keyword, the instrumentation does NOT work.

Comment: You have to create a bean for the http clients like RestTemplate, WebClient or OkHttp in the case that you use Retrofit

Comment: every body is talking about this line "We inject a ExchangeFilterFunction implementation that creates a span and, through on-success and on-error callbacks, takes care of closing client-side spans." but no body is telling the code to do so. I don't know how to implement ExchangeFilterFunction  filter which creates span.

Comment: It's done automatically - why do you want to inject it yourself?

Comment: If you are manually creating the instances of WebClient, you need to do it.